# Randomizing elements position into Array

Tags: java

I have a array of 4 elements. I need to randomize there position. What will be best way to do it  in Java.

Comment: So, what have you tried already?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following

```
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(myArrayOfWhatever));
```

Then you convert your List back into an Array. This might be bad if you have an array of a very large size, but yours is only 4.

source: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t302430-random-sorting-of-an-array.html (by googling [java array random sort] or [java array shuffle])

Answer (score 1):

A common algorithm for shuffling is the Fisher-Yates shuffle. The [wikipedia page](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Knuth_shuffle) has all the details needed

Answer (score 1):

For a lot of simple tasks like this, you'll find that there are often static methods to help you - either on the collections classes themselves, or on the "plural classes" - e.g. Arrays, Collections, etc.

(Also, note that Java 7 introduces several new plural classes with useful methods on them, such as Objects and Paths).

When looking to do something simple, stop and think if there's an existing helper method before going off and implementing a homebrew solution.